# Count number of condidates based on country and view them in JvectorMap legend

Tags: php, jquery, jvectormap

I am using [JvectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/) to show the Candidates Geographical details based on the number of candidates from a country. Like: i want to show the number of candidates from USA and same for other countries.

Example: USA, 5 Candidates

But it doesn't work. Instead it show 0 Candidates.
[image]

Therefore, my question is how to make JvectorMap to take the number of candidates based on country and display it in the map.

**Column name for user:** CandidatesName

**Column name for country:** Country

This is my code that i developed based on documentation of JvectorMap, but it is not working.

```
$("#world-map").vectorMap({
    map: "world_mill",
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    zoomOnScroll: false,
    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
    hoverColor: false,
    regionStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: "#e1e1e1",
            stroke: "none",
            "stroke-width": 0,
            "stroke-opacity": 1
        },
        hover: {
            "fill-opacity": 0.8
        },
        selected: {
            fill: "#8dc859"
        },
        selectedHover: {
        }
    },
    series: {
        regions: [{
            values: mapData,
            scale: ["#6fc4fe", "#2980b9"],
            normalizeFunction: "polynomial"
        }]
    },
    onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code)
    {
      el.html(el.html() + " (" + ((typeof mapData[code] == "undefined") ? "0" : mapData[code])   + " Candidates)");
    }
});
```

This is the div where i display the map.

```
<div id="world-map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Thanks in advance and looking forward to an answer. :)